# Java Passing Value To Another Class Issue

Tags: java

I have this class

```
public class A {
    private int number; //A number instance
    public A() { //At the beginning number is 0
        number=0;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void Str(String v) { //for given string number is gonna string's length
        setNumber(v.length());
    }
}
```

And I have this B class

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1=new A();//A class instance
        a1.Str("hello");//giving hello string
        System.out.println(a1.getNumber()); //this one is 0
    }
}
```

When I run this sample code a1.getNumber is 0. What could be wrong here??

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/rWDPcc

Comment: I've done it myself in the past, so I'll ask... did you save your files after making your last changes? Your posted code works as is.

Comment: Actually my problem is much bigger. I am asking this for maybe you guys show another way to passing values.